# plotting matrix-like data as points

Tags: gnuplot

I have data which looks like this:

```
label1: <set of increasing numbers 1..500>
label2: <set of increasing numbers 1..500>
```

etc

I would like to make a picture out of that would look something like:

```
label1    ...           ...............         .... .   . 
label2      ................           .............. 
etc

           1 2 3 ...                                       500
```

Can this be done with gnuplot in some relatively straightforward way?
I can transform the data into any form easily, i just don't know what to feed into gnuplot.

Comment: it's not clear to me how your input data really looks like. Is it columns with `label1` to `labelN` as column headers and `1`s =dot and  `0`s =no dot in the rows of the data field? Do you want a graphical plot or some ASCII output?

Comment: uh, it didn't format correctly.  Fixed.

Comment: sorry, still not clear. What do you want to have as x-axis (I assume the index from 1 to 500) and which value do you want to have plotted as y-value? A dot (or no-dot) in your schematic corresponds to what number in your data? If you are flexible in formatting your data, better format it in columns not in rows for gnuplot.

Comment: sample line is "label1 1 2 20 21 22 56 57 58 59"

Comment: do you maybe mean a heat map? http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.2/heatmaps.html

Comment: I think I just want a simple scatter plot actually :) Playing with it now.

Comment: So I created data file in the form of 2 columns, first label and second number.  I then plot it and it interprets first column as x and 2nd as y.  I tried swapping it with using 2:1 but it didn't help; also how do I make it draw labels using the first column?  Right now it just converts it to numbers it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe, we need some visual example here to find out what you really want.
The follwing should be a copy&paste code.
If you are reading your data from a file, replace `$Data` in the `plot` command by your filename, e.g. `'Data.dat'`. Does this come closer what you want?

```
reset session

$Data <<EOD
label1  label2  label3
1   3   6
2   6   9
20  23  31
21  26  34
22  25  29
56  50  44
57  58  55
58  60  70
59  65  85
EOD

set colorsequence classic
set key top left
set yrange [0.5:3.5]
plot for [i=1:*] $Data u i:(i):ytic(columnhead(i)) with points pointtype 7 pointsize 2 notitle
```

which should result in:

[image]

Addition:
The following code is an ugly workaround to basically transpose the data with gnuplot. The plotting result should be basically the same as above, except I made the rows different in length by removing and adding some points.

```
### plotting rows with different length
reset session

$DataInRows <<EOD
label1  1   2   20  21  22  56  57  58  59
label2  3   6   23  26  25  50  58
label3  6   9   31  34  29  44  55  70  88  90
EOD

stats $DataInRows u 0 nooutput   # get the number of rows
RowCount = STATS_records
array Rows[RowCount]   # define an array

# put rows as string into the array
set table $Dummy
    MaxColCount = 0
    set datafile separator "\n"        # full lines 
    # get the lines into array and at the same time determine the maximum number of columns
    plot $DataInRows u (Rows[$0+1]=stringcolumn(1), \
        MaxColCount = words(Rows[$0+1]) > MaxColCount ? words(Rows[$0+1]) : MaxColCount) \
        with table 
    set datafile separator whitespace  # set back to default
unset table
print MaxColCount

set print $Data  # print into dataset
do for [j=1:MaxColCount] {
    tmp = ''
    do for [i=1:RowCount] {
        tmp = i > 1 ? tmp."\t".word(Rows[i],j) : word(Rows[i],j)
    }
    print tmp
}
set print 

set colorsequence classic
set yrange [0.5:3.5]
plot for[i=1:RowCount] $Data u i:(i):ytic(columnhead(i)) w p pt 7 ps 2 notitle
### end of code
```

Comment: I want yaxis labels to be "label1", not numbers.   And I want all dots corresponding to label1 to be on the same horizontal line.  I guess I could just assign a unique number to each label and do that...

Comment: visually this is perfect.  No way to keep this as rows instead of columns?  And can you write few words explaining what i:(i):ytic() means?

Comment: gnuplot preferentially plots columns. I don't know of a good way to plot rows. You either create a cumbersome workaround with gnuplot or use an external tool to transpose your data before plotting. `i:(i):ytic(columnhead(i))` means it loops the columns from 1 to 3 and plots the values from column no. `i` as x-value and the constant value `(i)` (in each iteration) as y-value and takes the columnheader of column `i` as yticlabel.

Comment: and if column2 has fewer values, how do i make an empty cell?

Comment: I would use TAB `\t` as column separator. Then, e.g. the last row would just have to consecutive TABs: `65\t\t85`

Comment: `plot for [i=1:*] ...` should work with gnuplot 5.2.5 for autodetection of number of columns

Comment: hm.. looks like inserting tab doesn't work.  it collapses all values to the first column!

Comment: strange. Have you inserted `\t` as column separator everywhere not just at the lines where there is a shorter column? Also check the addition in my answer with the ugly workaround to plot your original data in rows "directly".

Comment: I inserted \ts correctly, the file imported to excel looks good.  I ended up just putting -1's and setting xscale to 0-1000 so they are not visible.  I appreciate the workaround for transposing inside gnuplot but refuse to look at it :)